# API integration using google app script calling methods on google sheets

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, woocommerce

I would like to add different API request on a spreadsheet where i already add some google app script code from [here](https://github.com/mithunmanohar/woocommerce-orders-google-sheets-integration/blob/master/wc-gc-integration.gs) in oder to retrieve all orders from a woocommerce external source, however now i want to add another API calling request which allows me to list all products on my woocommerce source. So i type a new function below, modify the endpoint to `/wp-json/wc/v3/products` according to woocommerce API rest documentation here [Woocommerce API rest doc](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#list-all-products). Here is the code i add to the Github code :

```
 // Custom code to v2 Woocommerce API
function start_syncv2() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(Products);
    fetch_products(sheet)

}

function fetch_products(sheet) {
  
    var ck = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(OrderDetails).getRange("B4").getValue();

    var cs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(OrderDetails).getRange("B5").getValue();

    var website = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(OrderDetails).getRange("B3").getValue();

    var surl = website + "/wp-json/wc/v3/sheet?consumer_key=" + ck + "&consumer_secret=" + cs + "&after=" + "&per_page=100"; 
    var url = surl
    Logger.log(url)

    var options =

        {
            "method": "GET",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            "muteHttpExceptions": true,

        };

    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

    Logger.log(result.getResponseCode())
    if (result.getResponseCode() == 200) {

        var params = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());
        Logger.log(result.getContentText());

    }

    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var temp = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName(sheet);

    var consumption = {};

var arrayLength = params.length;
    Logger.log(arrayLength)
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        Logger.log("dfsfsdfsf")
        var a;
        var container = [];
        a = container.push(params[i]["id"]);
        Logger.log(a)

        a = container.push(params[i]["name"]);

        a = container.push(params[i]["sku"]);

        a = container.push(params[i]["price"]); 

        a = container.push(params[i]["tax_status"]);

        a = container.push(params[i]["stock_status"]);
      
        a = container.push(params[i]["categories"]["name"]);
      
        a = container.push(params[i]["images"]);

        a = container.push(params[i]["attributes"]["options"]);

        a = container.push(params[i]["_links"]["self"]["href"]);

        var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

        var temp = doc.getSheetByName(sheet);

        temp.appendRow(container);

}
}
```

I have issue using google sheets calling method describe [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet). As i want my new API call request, i think my main problem is to select the right sheet into the spreadsheet.

Here is a copy of my spreadsheet : [Woocommerce-google sheets integration](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19rPTa6iOylsoBzO6neP3aAdFKYHqBrebNWzX0ZeWt6U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting and where you are getting it? Also, can you describe better your issue?

Comment: Did you take a look at the logging? You can right-click Google Apps Script project the project and go to `Executions`. Also, it seems that you are using a variable named `m` which is not defined.

Comment: @Kessy i get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (ligne 11, fichier "Code"), my issue is that i didn't define properly the new sheet in where i expect to import all the products from my API request, i think that is what is missing because the fetch orders function work.

Comment: @Martí 'm' is a value defined by cell B4 -->  'var manualDate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet_name).getRange("B6").getValue(); // Set your order start date in spreadsheet in cell B6

    var m = new Date(manualDate).toISOString();' but i made a mistake it was used in fetch orders funtion i forget to delete it.

Comment: As per your comments I would tell that you solved the issue. If it is that way, can you share it so others can benefit from it? If not, please update the question with the error and how do you have it now.

Comment: @Kessy I still get an error on line 11 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (ligne 11, fichier "Code")'

Comment: I think i use the wrong sheet calling method @Kessy

Comment: Can you share a copy of the sheets to see what does it have? Also, the sheet calling method looks good, one thing that can be wrong is the sheet_name parameter. Have you checked how is the function receiving this parameter?

Comment: @Kessy i've edited my question in order to share a copy of my sheet, I'm not familiar with testing function's parameter. All i know is that when i run my fetch_products function i get the TypeError as described above.

Comment: How is the `fetch_products`function run?  I can't see any other functions in the code calling that one

Comment: Sorry @Kessy i've misunderstood what you've asked me, i have updated my code.

Comment: @Kessy Now it tells me that the var "sheet" isn't defined with a ReferenceError